# Is there a debugging tool that echos back your HTTP request?

Tags: web-services, debugging, http

I swear I saw this once:

A website that just echoes back the request info (headers, url, method, params, etc) of all requests that come in.

Sort of like the opposite of [hurl.it](http://hurl.it)

Answer (score 3):

Found it: [httpbin is a webservice for testing http clients](http://httpbin.org).

the response just tells you the request it received.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) if you want a desktop application for doing this!